# Moving a WordPress site to a new domain - need help with an Apache htaccess URL rewrite rule

Tags: htaccess, apache, wordpress

I'm helping to move a WordPress site from one domain to another, which includes a change in permalink structure. I know I can use a *.htaccess* entry, but I'm not that well-versed (yet) in regular expressions.

I need to change this:

```
http://www.oldwebsite.com/2013/09/title-of-post.html
```

to this:

```
http://www.newwebsite.com/title-of-post
```

dropping the year, month, and `.html` from every URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve done this with Apache `mod_rewrite` and it works great.  Just add these three lines to either the *.htaccess* or Apache2 configuration on the old server. This should work well/cover all `.html` files as well as other variations:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^\ ]+)\.html
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([^\ ]+)\.html?$ http://www.newwebsite.com/$3 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([^\ ]+)\.html?$ http://www.newwebsite.com/$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?$ http://www.newwebsite.com/ [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/?$ http://www.newwebsite.com/ [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newwebsite.com/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

So the first two `RewriteRule` entries handle requests to the following URLs:

```
http://www.oldwebsite.com/2013/04/test.html 
http://www.oldwebsite.com/2013/test.html
```

And now send them to:

```
http://www.newwebsite.com/test
```

The next two `RewriteRule` entries handle requests to these directory level root URLs:

```
http://www.oldwebsite.com/2013/04/
http://www.oldwebsite.com/2013/
```

To this the base URL of your site:

```
http://www.newwebsite.com/
```

And the last `RewriteRule` is set to grab any other URLs that don’t fit the above criteria and send them to the main URL while passing the full param.

I would suggest that you test these out using `curl -I` like so:

```
curl -I http://www.oldwebsite.com/2013/04/test.html
```

That will show you the Apache header output & tell you exactly where pages are being redirected without having to deal with a full web browser headaches when debugging stuff like this.

Comment: It's great that you explained each part so users can learn from your answer!